# Referencing CSS files and JS files in Grails - twitter-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, grails

I have created a `Grails` project. And now i want to use `twitter-bootstrap`. I have installed `bootstrap` successfully. But i want to know how to reference the following 3 links in the `index.html page`

```
<r:require modules="bootstrap" />
<r:layoutResources />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script
    src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `bootstrap` plugin installed you just need to call the required module

BuidConfig.groovy

```
compile ":twitter-bootstrap:2.3.2"
```

Then in your `GSP`

```
<r:require modules='bootstrap-css, bootstrap-js, bootstrap-modal, ...'/>
```